# Session token empty for parse cloud code user query

Tags: parse-platform

I have written the following query to query a user with a given email and once found, return the session key.

Upon executing it returns an empty response.

I double checked that the user session entry actually exists and is linked to the user I am querying.

```js
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var email  = request.params.email;
  query.equalTo("email",email);
  query.first({
    success: function(user) {
      Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
      response.success(user.getSessionToken());
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      response.error(error);
    },
    useMasterKey: true
  });
```

Comment: are you use parse-server or parse.com?

Comment: parse.com, haven't migrated over yet

Comment: checkout the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you are using parse.com and not parse-server you need to write 
the following line of code:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

in the first line because you tell cloud code that you want to use master key before you are executing any request to the server. Also it's better to use Promises (according to the best practices)
so at the end your code should look like this:

**For running on parse.com**

```js
  // in parse.com - it's the first thing that you do
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var email = request.params.email;
  query.equalTo("email", email);
  query.first().then(function(user) {
    response.success(user.getSessionToken());
  }, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
  });
```

**For parse-server**

in parse-server you use **useMasterKey** and send it to the function. 
**Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();** will not work here.

```js
  // in parse-server - you send useMasterKey to the function 
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var email = request.params.email;
  query.equalTo("email", email);
  query.first({
    useMasterKey: true
  }).then(function(user) {
    response.success(user.getSessionToken());
  }, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
  });
```